# React Native opposite of onPress event (equivalent to JS mouseup?) Don't seem to exist: onPressUp, onPressRelease, onTouchUp, onUnPress events

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to implement a "press and hold" record button that stops recording upon release, but I can't find an event that is fired at the completion of a press event, like **onPressRelease** below:

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.recordStart} onPressRelease={this.recordStop}>
        <Image source={recordIcon} />
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
```

TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight, nor Button seem to have any events named liked:

- onPressComplete
- onPressUp
- onPressRelease
- onPressStop
- onTouchUp
- onUnPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the docs for [TouchableOpacity props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html#props) as an example, you'll see that the RN component docs often link to another component's props if they're inhereted. That's probably why you didn't see the props you were looking for. In this case, `TouchableOpacity` and `TouchableHighlight` get a lot of their props from `TouchableWithoutFeedback`.

There are a couple events you'll be interested in. See the documentation for [onPressIn](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html#props) and [onPressOut](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#onpressin).

Comment: But I need the onPress to start the recording.  Looking for "press and hold" to record while pressing.

Comment: In that case I need a pair of events: onPressDown and onPressUp.

Comment: Oh ok, you only asked about the release event in your question. I've edited my answer.